# TCPDF problem with semi transparent regions of pngs

Tags: php, png, tcpdf

I have got a problem with semi transparent regions of pngs in rendered pdfs by tcpdf. It seems like these regions get cut out. I suppose it is something related that it is treated like a 8-bit png? But i can't figure it out.

On the website itself the pngs are rendered as they should.

Here is my code:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
 //Page header
 public function Header() {
  // get the current page break margin
  $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
  // get current auto-page-break mode
  $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
  // disable auto-page-break
  $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
  // set bacground color
  $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), $this->getPageHeight(), "DF", "",   array(0,25,41));         
  // restore auto-page-break status
  $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
  // set the starting point for the page content
  $this->setPageMark();
 }
}


$pdf = new MYPDF("P", "mm", "A4", true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Image("test/neon_circle.png", 50, 50, 100, '', '', '', '', false, 300);

$pdf->Output("print.pdf", "I");
```

[image: That's the png]
[image: That is how it should look like]

[Thats the link to the pdf](https://www.isorauschen.at/test/neon_circle.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Yes it seems like there is a problem. I Think I figured out which methods causing it. So there is no problem in case imagick is available.

There is this method ImagePngAlpha and somewhere in the part where it uses the gd-library must be the problem.